# How many gates does a 7400TTL decice have?

Tags: digital-logic

How many gates does a 7400TTL decice have?
What type of devices inside this chip?

Comment: This is directly and clearly answered in the datasheet right where you'd expect to find it.

Answer (score 3):

A 7400 chip has 4 bipolar TTL NAND gates. Other 74nn chips will have different logic devices. Other 74xx00 chips will use different logic technologies.

[List of 7400 series integrated circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits)

[Texas Instruments Logic Migration Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/scyb032/scyb032.pdf)

[Texas Instruments Logic Guide 2009](http://www.ti.com/lit/sdyu001)

Comment: The original 7400 series had four gates per package. With SMT, you can now get a single 2 input NAND gate, e.g. [SN74LVC1G00](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SN74LVC1G00MDBVREP/296-22338-1-ND/1666911) in a SOT23-5 package. The 1G stands for 1 gate. These are CMOS, not TTL (LVC stands for low-voltage CMOS).

Answer (score 2):

The TTL stands for transistor-transistor logic. This is a series of logic chips, counters, shift registers etc. based upon the multiple emitter transistor. The were first produced in integrated circuit form in 1963 by Sylvania and later taken over by Texas, so they've been around a long time.

The first chip in the series is the 7400 and contains 4 (quad) 2 input NAND gates.

[image]

The basic characteristics of these chips is they run on 5V (not very tolerant about variation) , the inputs SOURCE current (give out rather than take in) and the outputs are designed to SINK current (fanout about 10).